# Ember.js transaction.rollback only works once (ember form reset)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Trying to get form reset functionality working. This implementation works once, but then will not work a second time.

The second time the cancel event is triggered the following error occurs:

Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `willSetProperty` on  while in state rootState.deleted.saved. Called with {reference: [object Object], store: , name: name}

```
App.NewPageRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    transaction = @get('store').transaction()
    transaction.createRecord(App.Page, siteId: params.site_id)


App.NewPageController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  submit: ->
    @content.get('transaction').save()

  cancel: ->
    @content.get('transaction').rollback()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs of `DS.Transaction::rollback`:

> After the transaction is rolled back, any records that belong to it
>   will return to the store's default transaction, and the current
>   transaction should not be used again.

A simple fix would be to create a new transaction after you roll back.

```
cancel: ->
  siteId = @get('model.siteId')
  @content.get('transaction').rollback()
  transaction = @get('store').transaction()
  newModel = transaction.createRecord(App.Page, siteId: siteId)
  @set('model', newModel)
```

Comment: Thanks! I had tried some form of everything except the @set('mode', newModel) portion. Any reason why the use of model and not content here? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Since we were getting 'model', it just made sense to me to set 'model'. But I think either 'model' or 'content' would work since content defaults to model if it's undefined.